# I am getting image links from api and converting into image. Sometimes there are invalid links. How do i check, if the link is valid image link?

Tags: java, android

I am getting image links from API and then converting it into image to display. If there is an invalid link, the code exits without executing rest of the code. How do I check if the link is a valid image link? Is it possible to check?

example of the link i got 
https://bsmedia.business-standard.com/_media/bs/img/article/default/1190514/full-119051400288.jpg

Comment: As the website return error 404, it would be posible to check the http response and filter that way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can check with

```
var isValidUrl = URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)
```

Then you can get the name of file with

```
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
```

Then you can get the extension of file with

```
var extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)
```

Now just compare the extension with any extension like `jpg`, `jpeg`, `png` etc. to check for valid image.